# TensorExpand, TensorProduct and Distribution over Scalars

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, tensors

Consider:

```
TensorExpand[( b1 x )\[TensorProduct] (b1 x + b2), 
 Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]
(*x^2 b1\[TensorProduct]b1 + x b1\[TensorProduct]b2*)
```

This works as expected. The scalar x is extracted. However if I eliminate the "b2" term, the tensor product is no more distributed over "Times":

```
TensorExpand[( b1 x )\[TensorProduct] (b1 x), 
 Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]
(*(b1 x)\[TensorProduct](b1 x)*)
```

Has somebody an explanation and workaround?

Comment: TensorExpand works best when you provide assumptions for all symbols. So, add an assumption for `b1` too.

Comment: @Carl Woll Hi, b1 is a base vector, but the assumption b1 \[Element] Vector does not change anything. Any idea?

Comment: Try adding `b1 \[Element] Vectors[d]` instead.

Comment: Sure, is only a typo, But try it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

[`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) works best when you provide assumptions for all symbols. So, add an assumption for b1 too:

```
TensorExpand[
    TensorProduct[b1 x, b1 x],
    Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals && b1 ∈ Vectors[d]
]
```

> x^2 TensorProduct[b1, b1]

Comment: Thank's a lot. I was not clear to me that you need an undetermined dimension like Vector[d]. But the help definitely states it. Always something to learn.

Comment: Unfortunately TensorExpand seems really buggy.As you noted, b1 ∈ Vectors[d] works. But e.g. {b1} ∈ Vectors[d] does not work.

Comment: @DanielHuber You can't use lists for tensors, use Alternatives instead, e.g., `(b1 | b2) ∈ Vectors[d]`. The problem with using lists is that `{1} ∈ Vectors[1]` is true, but `{1} ∈ Vectors[2]` is false, so `{b1} ∈ Vectors[d]` is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank's, you seem to know all the little details, keep on.